# append div to another div by uisng tag name?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video, html5-video

I have a container called adcontainer, now I have another div which contains a video  generated dynamically to the dom, this new div which are generated dynamically does not have id or class juts tag name,

Now I want to append this new divs to the adconatiner

Here is HTML

```
<div id="adcontainer"></div>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
   <video src="videos/video.mp4" autoplay="true"></video>
</div>
```

Js

```
var adContainer = document.getElementById('#adcontainer')
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
var parentEl = video.parentNode;
adContainer.appendChild(parentEl)
```

unfortunately, this is not working, what is wrong here?

Comment: `var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `getElementById()` doesnt require `#`
- `getElementsByTagName()` returns a HTMLCollection, so use `[0]`

```js
var adContainer = document.getElementById('adcontainer')
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
var parentEl = video[0].parentNode;
adContainer.appendChild(parentEl)
```

```html
<div id="adcontainer"></div>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
   <video src="videos/video.mp4" autoplay="true"></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run javascript after page is loaded.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var adContainer = document.getElementById('adcontainer')
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
    var parentEl = video[0].parentNode;
    adContainer.appendChild(parentEl)
});
```